# please give me particular account as regard evaluate in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I use the TensorFlow create a model and evaluate it, the result is as follows:

```
28481/1 - 2s - loss: 0.0366 - AUC: 0.8978 - accuracy: 0.9992 - binary_crossentropy: 0.0649
[0.06904765333583215, 0.8978283, 0.9991924, 0.06492031]
```

What is the 0.06904765333583215 mean?

Comment: the code is as follows:    result = model.evaluate(inputX_test,  inputY_test, verbose=2)
print(result)

Comment: how many classes do you have in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the return value of the `tf.keras.Model.evaluate()` method is documented at this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable#evaluate

It appears that your model has a loss and three metrics (AUC, accuracy and binary_crossentropy). So the four elements of the list returned by `evaluate()` are the final average values of the loss, AUC, accuracy and binary_crossentropy, respectively. They are averaged across the examples of the evaluation data set you fed to the `evaluate()` call.

So to answer your original question, `0.06904765333583215` is the average loss value among the examples in your evaluation set.